# Python: How can I ensure module aliases used in functions are correct?

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, alias

I'm trying to make a function foo available for anyone to use.  How can I ensure they are importing modules with specific aliases?

```
def foo(object):
    objdtypes = (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.core.series.Series)
    if isinstance(object,objdtypes): 
        print("It's there")
```

Right now I'm doing something like this which doesn't seem sustainable if they must use different aliases for numpy and pandas.

```
def checkAlias():
    while True:
        try:
            np.BUFSIZE
            pd.BooleanDtype.name
            return True
        except NameError:
            print("\n" +
                  "Please add the following commands to your script and try again:\n" +
                  "import numpy as np\n"+
                  "import pandas as pd")
            return
```

Comment: When you say "make a function foo available for anyone to use", are you expecting them to copy-paste your function into their files? This kind of thing is only a problem for people copy-pasting your function - if you're distributing a module, it doesn't matter what aliases your module's users do or don't use. *Your* code will have the imports your code needs.

Answer (score 1):

Import the packages within the function instead of relying on the global scope.

```py
def foo(obj):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    objdtypes = (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.core.series.Series)
    if isinstance(obj, objdtypes): 
        print("It's there")
```

Also do not use `object` as a variable name because that will shadow the builtin `object`.

Answer (score 1):

When someone imports your function any required modules will be imported with the alias that you have used. For example, you can create a file called, say, `mymodule.py`, containing:

```py
import numpy as np

def myfunc(arg):
    return np.sin(arg)
```

If you then open a Python terminal session and use:

```py
from mymodule import myfunc

print(myfunc(2))
0.9092974268256817
```

it will work perfectly well. It will even work if you import numpy with a different alias in the terminal session, e.g.,

```py
import numpy as blah
from mymodule import myfunc

print(myfunc(2))
0.9092974268256817
```

After importing `myfunc`, if you look at:

```
myfunc.__globals__
{'__builtins__': {'ArithmeticError': ArithmeticError,
...
'__file__': 'module.pyc',
 '__name__': 'module',
 '__package__': None,
 'myfunc': <function module.myfunc>,
 'np': <module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>}
```

you see that it contains the expected alias for numpy (`np`), and that's what it will use.

Comment: Great explanation!  Thank you.